# face recognition can't detect if image face is not on portrait

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I try using face recognition from this link: [face recognition](https://face-recognition.readthedocs.io/en/latest/face_recognition.html)

then modif the code like this, main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgitb, cgi
cgitb.enable()
print("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8")

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
import base64
import simplejson as json
import re
import face_recognition
import numpy as np
import io
from imageio import imread
from PIL import Image
import datetime
import os, errno
import shutil

params = cgi.FieldStorage()
now = datetime.datetime.now()
date = str(now)
date2 = date.replace(" ","")
img = params.getvalue('img')
data1 = json.loads(img)
data2 = data1['img2']['data']

numparray = data1['img1']
numparray2 = numparray.replace(" ", "+")

b=bytes(numparray2)
imgdata = base64.b64decode(b)

os.makedirs(date2)
with open(date2+"/img1.png", "wb") as f:
    f.write(imgdata)

image = face_recognition.load_image_file(date2+'/img1.png')

try:
    face_encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(image)[0]
    #print("face_encode = ".format(face_encode))
except IndexError:
    print("encode image failed")
    quit()

known_faces = []
y = 1
for images in data2:
    ir = images.replace(" ", "+")
    ib = bytes(ir)
    imagedata = base64.b64decode(ib)
    x = str(y)
    with open(date2+"/compare"+x+".png", "wb") as g:
        g.write(imagedata)
    compare = face_recognition.load_image_file(date2+"/compare"+x+".png")
    try:
        compare_encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(compare)[0]
        #print("face_encode = ".format(face_encode))
    except IndexError:
        print("encode image compare failed")
        quit()
    known_faces.append(compare_encode)
    y = y+1

results = face_recognition.face_distance(known_faces, face_encode)

datahasil = []
#hasilakhir = "{"
for i, face_distance in enumerate(results):
    h = "{:.2}".format(face_distance, i)
    #hasilakhir = hasilakhir+"compare{}"
    datahasil.append(h)

hasilakhir = ','.join(datahasil)

shutil.rmtree(date2, ignore_errors=True)

print("{\"hasilcompare\" : \"" +hasilakhir+ "\"}")
```

the final result is compare between 2 image and give the score, in case photo of image is potrait compare is successfull, but when one of image is not on potrait (face not on potrait potision) or like face angle more than 90 degree, that give error message in catch encode failed..

i have try another way with face detection before sending 2 image to main.py to detect the image in face but when it can't detect faces i try to rotate the image untill the code detect face, but sometimes face detection can detect face with angle 90degree but in face recognition(main.py) still can't read the face.

```
code of rotate is here, rotate.py:import numpy as np
import cv2
from scipy import ndimage, misc
import os
from PIL import Image


face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

for counter in range (0, 4):
    img = cv2.imread('img/1.jpg')
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    if(len(faces) == 1):
        i = False
        print ("face found")
        break
    else:
        print("no face found")
        i = False
        img = Image.open("img/1.jpg")
        img.rotate(90).save("img/1.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think this is the problem with the library. I tested it on the same image. Once after rotation and once on the original image. It does not detect in the rotated image, both the `face_locations` and `face_encodings` are empty lists.